# JwtClaimsSetVerifier is deprecated. What is the modern equivalent?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using a very recent version of spring security. I want to validate the aud claim. There used to be a very clean and easy hook to do so: `JwtClaimsSetVerifier`

See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-2-verify-claims

Implement the interface, make it a bean, done.

But now it is deprecated and I see no indication of a replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: What was your solution? Is it still WIP?

Answer (score 0):

This it's the official document to follow
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide
still a WIP